# How to display salted password as a string

Tags: php

I have a piece of code below where it echos a salted password:

```
            $pass = rand();
            $pass = md5($pass);
            $pass = substr($pass, 0, 15);
            $pass = md5(md5("g3f".$pass."rt4"));
```

Now if I echo $pass, then it will output this for example:

```
8723d9c8a8b2af798be25fd07ab0ff0a
```

But what I want to do is echo the password itself so that for example instead of displaying the above it will display the string which is "password".

How can this be achieved?

Thanks

Comment: Hmm i thought the sin of salted passwords is to encrypt the password. You can't get the password back.

Comment: I want the password hashed when it is in the database but I want the string of the password to be displayed in the email because if the user entered in the salted password in their login, it won't let them as that is not their actual password.

Comment: The user shouldn't enter a salted password, they should enter a passsword - aside from knowing that it's secure, they shouldn't even care that there is a salt as well, let alone know that salt

Comment: And using MD5 twice doesn't make the password twice as secure, it makes it less secure

Comment: @jeroen Many services email randomly generated passwords. If you have the email you can reset the password in most circumstances... so why not?

Comment: It won't make a difference but less secure? Not sure how you came to that conclusion.

Comment: He's randomly generating a password for the user. How exactly do you guys expect the user to know what that is without it being emailed? My guess is this IS the reset password function, it's similar to what I do.

Comment: @RickCalder, simply by not generating it at all. There are ways of alternative authentication as I've already mentioned in my answer. It's a bad idea to send a password over email, doesn't matter it's randomly generated.

Comment: @Stony Why you ever want your password back??

Comment: @walther Good points, I should really readdress that portion of our site when I have a moment.

Comment: I know its not the bast idea and I will put in my evaluation that security will be a lot better for the passowrd in the future. All I have done is sent an email to the user on their new password but I also mentioned in the auto generate email that this password should be stored in a safe place and it is best to delete this email for security reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't overwrite the variable `$pass`;

```
    $pass = rand();
    $md5pass = md5($pass);
    $md5pass = substr($md5pass, 0, 15);
    $md5pass = md5(md5("g3f".$md5pass."rt4"));
```

MD5 hashing especially with a salt is a one way process. You can't reverse it.

Any good password system does not store the original password but stores the hashed copy, it then verifies the user entered it correctly by hashing their input and comparing the two.

Comment: @user1723760 yes, in your example you overwrote `$pass` with the hashed version, this copy `$pass` stays the same.

Comment: Thanks I will mark the answer when I come back, have to wait 10 mins.

Answer (score 10):

You can't. Hashing is a one way street. If you want to hide a string that needs to be shown later, you'd need to use encryption instead. However, this is a taboo when it comes to passwords.

To address the second part of the question, you should NEVER send user passwords via email. Implement a server-side solution (for instance use security questions + verification of their email) and after authentication allow users to change their passwords directly on the website.

Oh, and one more thing - **forget about MD5**!!!!

Comment: In theory, @walther is totally right, but in practice, there's a way : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table

Comment: @LaurentBrieu That's why salts exist and render rainbow tables practically useless. A rainbow table is just a massive index of prehashed strings (slightly simplified).

Comment: @LaurentBrieu, you, in practice, as a site admin, would consider using rainbow tables for showing user passwords? Furthermore, can you imagine using rainbow tables or brute force attacks done by website itself to get user passwords? Last, but not least, he's talking about salted passwords - your rainbow tables are useless as George already said...

Comment: Yes, i know that @GeorgeReith :) But with some powerful computers, even password with salt can be indexed (even if it's take long time) :)

Comment: @walther, I'm not saying that he can use rainbow tables.. Neither do I. I'm talking about rainbow tables, just about the "one way street" point.

Comment: @LaurentBrieu It's still a one way street, just like it can be bruteforced. You aren't actually reversing the algorithm. What you are saying is that they are crackable.

Comment: Yes, I agree @GeorgeReith. It's not a way to reverse the algorithm, but a way to bypass it. Anyway, that's not the subject of the question :)

Answer (score 0):

```
        $pass = rand();
        $originalPass = $pass;
        $pass = md5($pass);
        $pass = substr($pass, 0, 15);
        $pass = md5(md5("g3f".$pass."rt4")); 
        echo $originalPass;
```

Or

```
    $pass = rand();
    echo $pass;
    $pass = md5($pass);
    $pass = substr($pass, 0, 15);
    $pass = md5(md5("g3f".$pass."rt4"));
```

Comment: You should never store users password in plain text... Violation of multiple principles, not mentioning that double md5 or using md5 at all!

Comment: I wasn't suggesting he store it that way by any means, just that he could output it that way.

Comment: @RickCalder, in which scenario you'd want to show the password of the user?

Comment: He asked a question, I answered it. I did not say anything in my post about storing it, nor did he say anything in his question about storing it. You're assuming things and being argumentative for no reason.